socket.io on node server - connection not successful on deployment but worked in development
Problem
I have set up socket.io on node server following advice here and socketio docs. It was working successfully and i can see server log can print out connected when i run localhosted client. However connection unsuccessful when i run the remote hosted client react app,i.e.   console.log("connected") is not printed in server log.
connection worked on postman too
localhosted client-localhosted server-> socket.io connect successful
localhosted client-render hosted server-> socket.io connect successful
render hosted client-render hosted server-> socket.io connect unsuccessful
Setup

Hosting server and client both on render.com
Node server configured using express with rest api and socket.io (p.s. rest api is working)
Client using react

Server code
const supabase = require("./configdb.js");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

//socket.io
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = {
  cors: {
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://project001-ejm9.onrender.com/"],// both development and production  path
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
};
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);

//set up socket connection to record online user
let onlineUsers = {};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connected");
  socket.on("userEntered", (user) => {
    onlineUsers[socket.id] = user;
    io.emit("updateUserList", Object.values(onlineUsers));
    console.log(Object.values(onlineUsers));
    console.log(user);
  });

  socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    delete onlineUsers[socket.id];
    io.emit("updateUserList", Object.values(onlineUsers));
    console.log("disconnect");
  });
});

// Set port, listen for requests.
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}.`);
});

// Add routes routes.
require("./routes/chat.routes.js")(express, app);


Client code
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const socket = io("https://project001db-11.onrender.com/");

export const useSocket = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return useSocket;
};

export const useRegisterOnlineUser = (username) => {
  const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!username) return;

    const user = { username: username };
    socket.emit("userEntered", user, () => {
      console.log("emitted event-userConnected");
    });

    socket.on("updateUserList", (users) => {
      setOnlineUsers(users);
      console.log("updateUserList event received", users);
    });

    // Clean up on component unmount
    return () => {
      socket.off("updateUserList");
    };
  }, [username]);

  return onlineUsers;
};


Checked on stack overflow and online resource for solutions:


suspect this is SSL issue, but tried to do SSL test on "https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=project001db-11.onrender.com"
but got grade A, seems my server is already configured to handle https request ?

tried to connect server with postman, also working


i have added error message for debug
  socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
      console.error("Connection error:", err);
    });

below is the error message
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://project001db-11.onrender.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P1VQHOx' from origin 'https://project001-ejm9.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

polling.js:298 
        
        
GET https://project001db-11.onrender.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P1VQHOx net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)


socketio.js:34  Connection error: Error: xhr poll error
    at polling.onError (transport.js:38:37)
    at yd.<anonymous> (polling.js:218:18)
    at Yu.emit (index.js:136:20)
    at yd.onError (polling.js:320:14)
    at polling.js:294:30


It seems like this issue might be due to the limitations of Render's free tier. Try using Glitch. I use this platform for my socket projects.

i think it does support socket project after some research...but not sure whats the issue

Yes, Render do support the socket connections but due to it's 15mins inactivity might be the cause of your client socket not connecting to your server socket.
